# Add fields in DevExpress Pivot using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, devexpress, pivot, devextreme

I'm looking at this template to build a web application: https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/PivotGrid/FieldChooser/AngularJS/Light/

In the example there are static data. I have to retrieve them from the server. So, I wrote this:

```
$scope.testData = [];
$scope.pivotGridDataSource = new DevExpress.data.PivotGridDataSource({
   fields: [{
     caption: "Nome",
     dataField: "fullName",
     area: "row"
    }, {
     caption: "Country",
     dataField: "country",
    area: "column"
  }, {
    caption: "Count",
    dataField: "countOne",
    dataType: "number",
    summaryType: "sum",
    area: "data"
  }],
     store: $scope.testData
  });

  $scope.pivotGridOptions = {
     allowSortingBySummary: true,
     allowSorting: true,
     allowFiltering: true,
     showBorders: true,
     dataSource: $scope.pivotGridDataSource,
     fieldChooser: {
        enabled: false
     }
   },

   $scope.fieldChooserOptions = {
      dataSource: $scope.pivotGridDataSource,
         texts: {
            allFields: "All",
            columnFields: "Columns",
            dataFields: "Data",
            rowFields: "Rows",
            filterFields: "Filter"
           },
          width: 400,
          height: 400,
          bindingOptions: {
             layout: "layout"
          }
      };

  // Now I call the server to retrieve data
  $scope.getTestData = () => {
     $scope.testData.length = 0;
     result.forEach(e => {
         $scope.testData.push(e);
     );
     $scope.pivotGridDataSource.reload();
  }

  $scope.getTestData();
```

The problem is that when the data are loaded, in the Fields below it shows just the fields written at the beginning (so the name, the count and the country). But I saw in the demo that it should be display ALL parameters of the object.
For example, if the object is so structured:

```
{ "name": "Test1", "country": "Germany", "creationDate": "xxx", "surname": "yyy" }
```

So, I expect that in the fields there should be ALL parameters, so name, country, creationDate, surname. So, I did this at the beginning:
I changed $scope.testData = [] into:

```
$scope.testData = [{ "name": "", "country": "", "creationDate": "", "surname": "" }]
```

so the component will preparare all fields. And this works. But what if the server gives me back an Object that has another parameters? How can I display them?
I tried so after the calling and before the reload():

```
    let fields = $scope.pivotGridDataSource.fields();
    let newField = {
        llowExpandAll: false,
        allowFiltering: true,
        allowSorting: true,
        allowSortingBySummary: true,
        caption: "This is a new field",
        dataField: "newField",
        dataType: "string",
        displayFolder: "",
        index: fields.length
    }

    $scope.pivotGridDataSource.fields().push(newField);
    $scope.pivotGridDataSource.reload();
```

But it doesn't work yet. Worse, it does not even initialize the Pivot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *fieldChooser* uses the *store* fields, in this case *$scope.testData* fields, in your code I see your store is first declared (as null or with some format as you described) and then you have a function to fill it.

I don't know how your code looks and why you create your store that way, but that is basically your problem (the flow).

In the [sample code](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/PivotGrid/FieldChooser/AngularJS/Light/) the flow is:

1. Store with data (static in this case)
2. PivotGridDataSource
3. FieldChooser

In your code the flow is:

1. Store (empty)
2. PivotGridDataSource
3. FieldChooser
4. Store (fill) --> at this point your FieldChooser has been initialized with the fields of the empty version of your store so not much to do (in Jquery you could re-create your object, you dan do it using [Jquery within AngularJs](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/15_2/Guide/Data_Visualization/Basics/Widget_Basics_-_AngularJS/#Destroy_a_Widget) see a simple [code sample here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q574456/best-way-to-destroy-dxchart-to-re-render-dxpiechart) and below)

   $('#chartContainer').dxChart('instance').dispose();
   $('#chartContainer').dxPieChart({
       ...
   });

To avoid all of this you can just use the *DevExpress.data.CustomStore* and your flow will be basically identical to the demo.

Comment: I didn't understand, what should I take from the link https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q574456/best-way-to-destroy-dxchart-to-re-render-dxpiechart ? However, I need to use this structure because the table will have multiple types of data (in relation to the page I come from), and each set of information is retrieved by the server

Comment: I edited my answer showing how to destroy and re-create an object, that is what the answer shows $('#chartContainer').dxChart('instance').dispose(); $('#chartContainer').dxPieChart({ ... });